# Should I inherit react props from HTMLProps<HTMLElement>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, inheritance, react-props

I am using React with TypeScript and I would like to allow components have all HTML attributes.

```
interface MyComponentProps extends HTMLProps<HTMLElement> {

}
```

However, sometimes I need set my custom prop type, for example `onClick`:

```
interface MyComponentProps extends HTMLProps<HTMLElement> {
    onClick?: (count: number) => void
}
```

But in TypeScript, I can't change already existing property in child interface. Is there any simple solution for this?

I just think one of the folowing:

- Define my own parent interfaces instead of `HTMLProps` *(requires extra import in each file and many custom interfaces)*,
- Rename my custom props *(yes, but I would like use common prop names like `onClick` or `data` instead of  `onComponentClick` or `_data`)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this. First, define your props, then omit them from the `HTMLProps` and then union your props with it.

```js
interface OverrideProps {
  onClick?: (count: number) => void;
}

type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

type MyComponentProps = Omit<
  React.HTMLProps<HTMLElement>,
  keyof OverrideProps
> &
  OverrideProps;
```